# dynamic form fields insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code, that inserts data into my sql database

```
for ($i = 0, $len = count($_POST['ItemID']); $i < $len; $i++) 
 {
         $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO services (ItemID, JCard, CusID, Jcardid, ItemNo, PernNo, jcDescription) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",

         GetSQLValueString($_POST['ItemID'][$i], "int"),
         GetSQLValueString($_POST['JCard'][$i], "int"),
         GetSQLValueString($_POST['CusID'][$i], "text"),
         GetSQLValueString($_POST['Jcardid'][$i], "text"),
         GetSQLValueString($_POST['ItemNo'][$i], "int"),
         GetSQLValueString($_POST['PernNo'][$i], "text"),  
         GetSQLValueString($_POST['JcDescription'][$i], "text"));
```

the form has generated dynamic fields;

problem is only one row (first row) is inserted to the database

Comment: can you add the output of the `print_r($_POST)`? and your html markup?

Comment: 1/ Use prepared statements instead of inserting (arguably sanitised) strings directly into your query, 2/ did you check the length of the $_POST['ItemID'] array?, 3/ do you execute the query each loop or do you append the values of each row to the same, big query? I think a single big query is preferred to a lot of small queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['ItemID']); $i++) 
{
     $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO services (ItemID, JCard, CusID, Jcardid, ItemNo, PernNo, jcDescription) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",

     GetSQLValueString($_POST['ItemID'][$i], "int"),
     GetSQLValueString($_POST['JCard'][$i], "int"),
     GetSQLValueString($_POST['CusID'][$i], "text"),
     GetSQLValueString($_POST['Jcardid'][$i], "text"),
     GetSQLValueString($_POST['ItemNo'][$i], "int"),
     GetSQLValueString($_POST['PernNo'][$i], "text"),  
     GetSQLValueString($_POST['JcDescription'][$i], "text");
}
```

Comment: still the same inserting only the first row

Comment: Try print_r($_POST) and tell me the result.

Comment: it display        Array ( )